# Retrieve inner text with spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract text out of an arbitrary block of HTML.  Naive attempt:

```
$('<div><p>Some</p>Inner<div>Text</div></div>').text()
```

This gives `SomeInnerText`, but I want `Some Inner Text`

What is a better way to extract text out of HTML, while maintaining some concept of the visual structure with which the HTML would be rendered?

In the example above, new lines between block elements would be great & spaces could be a sort of "flattened" output.

Comment: "while leaving spaces between block elements" --- there are **no** spaces there. So there is nothing to *leave*.

Comment: @zerkms fair enough, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression to inject spaces before closing tags:

```
$('<div><p>Some</p>Inner<div>Text</div></div>'.replace(/</g, ' <')).text();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/uau6S/

Comment: I wonder if the text injected this way will be preserved across browsers when .text() is called.  It sounds like modern browsers should do this.  Oldies like IE6/7 may not - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3144

Comment: I've confirmed this does the trick on IE9+ and any recent version of Chrome/Firefox.  Didn't test older browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can insert '&nbsp' into your script:

```
$('<div><p>Some&nbsp;</p>Inner&nbsp;<div>Text</div></div>').text();
```

Comment: It doesn’t have to be non-breaking.

Comment: you remember adding ';' after &nbsp

Comment: I've updated the question - this should be for an arbitrary block of HTML.. "change the source string" doesn't count :)

Comment: I don’t know what you’re talking about, but I do know you’re sockpuppet-voting on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *can* extend jQuery to do that:

```
$.fn.textRespectingBlocks = function() {
    return this.map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var display = $this.css('display');
        var isBlock = display !== 'none' && display !== 'inline' && display !== 'inline-block' && display !== 'inline-flex' && display !== 'inline-table';
        var childText = Array.prototype.map.call(this.childNodes, function(node) {
            if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                return $(node).textRespectingBlocks();
            }

            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                return node.nodeValue;
            }

            return '';
        }).join('');

        return isBlock ? ' ' + childText + ' ' : childText;
    }).get().join('');
};
```

Do a `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s(?=\s)/g, '')` on the result, if you like.

Comment: And maybe add `-webkit-inline-flex`, etc.

Comment: This is a very smart solution and also solves the problem in a very robust way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding the spaces yourself will do the trick. However, due to the variations in the way that html is parsed by different browsers, this may result in variations of white space across browsers.

```
$('<div> <p>Some</p> Inner <div>Text</div></div>').text()
```